# Best (circle) for a (member) depening on best common

Tags: mysql, database

Dear stackoverflow members,

I have four tables: members, circles, circle_members, and member_relations.

You might check this link to have a clear view on database schema.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a47a6/1

Now,

John, which is the member with the id of 1, is related to two members [2, 4].

Yet, John is not a member of any circle. I want to add John to the (best) circle.

By best I mean, the circle with the most common member ids between circle_members, and member_relations.

In this case, John will be added to circle #1, because there are two common ids in this circle with his relations; specifically [2, 4]. But will not be added to circle #2 because there is only one common id, which is [4]. And if you notice, circle #3 is not appropriate because there is no common id for this one.

I want to make this functionality using SQL, MySQL is prefered.

Best regards,
Hussam.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: You missed out the bit where you tell us how you worked out that 2, 6 were common members. Common to what?

Comment: I modified the question by adding the explaination of (common).

Comment: Thanks. But I still haven't got my head around member_relations and what data is in there and what it means. No - I've got it now. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select circle_id, count(*)
from member_circles mc
inner join
(
    -- Get related members
    select relatedMemberId
    from member_relations
    where member_id = 1 -- That's John
) x on x.relatedMemberId = c.member_id
group by circle_id
order by count(*) desc
```

(I've assumed that member_relations has columns member_id and relatedMemberId. Change as appropriate.)

This produces a list with the most appropriate circle first.

Cheers -

Comment: This is the query after modifying:

select circle_id, count(*)
from circle_members cm
inner join
(
    -- Get related members
    select member_b
    from member_relations
    where member_a = 1 -- That's John
) x on x.member_b = cm.member_id
group by circle_id
order by count(*) desc;